# Save google map for offline use

Tags: android, google-maps

I am  doing a project on Google map. My requirement is to save the Google map when online and to use in  offline mode. In Ios, they used GMSTileURLConstructor. In the same, Is there any probabilities to save map. If yes, can you provide me any idea or link.

```
    -(void)ViewOfflineMap
    {
          GMSTileURLConstructor urls = ^(NSUInteger x, NSUInteger y, NSUInteger zoom) {
               NSString *strMap=[NSString      stringWithFormat:@"http://mt0.google.com/vt/x=%ld&y=%ld&z=%ld",(long)x,(long)y,(long)zoom];
               return [NSURL URLWithString:strMap];
          };

    GMSURLTileLayer *layer=[GMSURLTileLayer tileLayerWithURLConstructor:urls];
    layer.zIndex=100;
    layer.map=mapView_;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one solution. We can save map as tiles using UrlTileProvider. It saves the map tiles, based on the zooming level and x and y axis covered area in your screen.

```
TileProvider tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
    @Override
    public URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {

        String s = String.format(
                "http://my.image.server/images/%d%d%d.png", zoom, x, y);

        if (!checkTileExists(x, y, zoom)) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return new URL(s);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }

    private boolean checkTileExists(int x, int y, int zoom) {
        int minZoom = 12;
        int maxZoom = 16;

        if ((zoom < minZoom || zoom > maxZoom)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
};

tileOverlay = map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions()
        .tileProvider(tileProvider));
```

Answer (score 0):

Google maps already does it, what you see once will be cached

Comment: This must be a comment,

Comment: In my application I used the map for plot the places which  i need.  and i need to use the plotted places in offline.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Google Maps Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms):

> 8.1 Definitions.
>
> (b) "***Content***" means any content provided through the Service (whether
>   created by Google or its third party licensors), including map and
>   terrain data, photographic imagery, traffic data, places data
>   (including business listings), or any other content.
>
> 10.1.3 Restrictions against Data Export or Copying.
>
> (b) **No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of *Content***. You must not
>   pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: ...
>
> ... limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance...

To answer your question: no, you may not save Google Maps data for offline use.

Comment: But this is possible in IOS application and Google maps also. Then why we can't?